# A multivariate function is convex in one variable and increases in another and I know the value at one point. Can I sign the mixed partial derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a function $g(x,y)$ with the following properties:

- $\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x} <0, $ $\frac{\partial^2 g(x,y)}{\partial x^2} >0.$
- The variable $x \in [0,1]$ and $g(0,y)=\infty$ and  $g(1,y)=0$.
- We know  $\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y} >0$ in the domain $x \in [0,1]$.

$g(x,y)$ is a nice function (continuous, twice differentiable etc.). Are the properties above sufficient to have
$$\frac{\partial^2 g(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} < 0?$$
I think the conditions are sufficient because $g(1,y)=0$ implies that  $\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y} \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 1$ and the strict convexity of $g$ in $x$ implies that $\frac{\partial^2 g(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} $ must have a constant sign. Is that correct?